# Comma separation in the Text Field in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

in my application i have a Custom text box  with `BasicEditField.FILTER_NUMERIC`. When the user enter the value in the field the comma should be added to the Currency format .

EX:1,234,567,8.... like this.

In my code i tried like this.

```java
protected boolean keyUp(int keycode, int time) {
    String entireText = getText();
    if (!entireText.equals(new String(""))) {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(entireText);

        String txt = Utile.formatNumber(val, 3, ",");// this will give the //comma separation format 
        setText(txt);// set the value in the text box
    }
    return super.keyUp(keycode, time);
}
```

it will give the correct number format... when i set the value in the text box it will through the `IllegalArgumentException`. I know `BasicEditField.FILTER_NUMERIC` will not allow the charector like comma(,)..

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You need to make your own filter extending TextFielter, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/text/TextFilter.html. And later need to set that filter to the BasicEditField instance.

Comment: BasicEditField.FILTER_NUMERIC is connected to locale of your BlackBerry. Some locales using different approach for periods separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this way and it works fine...

```
public class MyTextfilter extends TextFilter {
private static TextFilter _tf = TextFilter.get(TextFilter.REAL_NUMERIC);

public char convert(char character, int status) {
    char c = 0;

    c = _tf.convert(character, status);
    if (c != 0) {
        return c;
    }

    return 0;
}

public boolean validate(char character) {
    if (character == Characters.COMMA) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean b = _tf.validate(character);
    if (b) {
        return true;

    }

    return false;
}
}
```

and call like this

```
editField.setFilter(new MyTextfilter());
```